# Extract string from the URL

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract a string from the URL. I have the following URL :

```
https://optim.actiontec.com/aei-api/users/R1RCQTY1MjA1MDYyMDc%3D
```

I want to extract the string after **users/** and store it in a variable that I can use. I tried using the regular expression extractor but it did not work.

My second issue is extracting stuff from request headers. I dont know much about it  but can we extract stuff from Request headers?
This is my request header -

```
GET /aei-api/main/R1RCQTY1MjA1MDYyMDc%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: optim.actiontec.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Token: 03a580b082140ee7
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
X-User-Id: R1RCQTY1MjA1MDYyMDc=
Referer: https://optim.actiontec.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

And I am looking to extract X-User-Id.I want to use the header value and pass it to other headers. Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: show your current code/regexp (even if broken)

Comment: This is what I am using : /users/(.+?). Doing so gives me just the first charachter i.e R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regex configuration would be like this:

```
Field to check: Request Header
Reference Name: var
Regular Expression: X-User-Id: (\w+.)
Template: $1$
Match No: 1
```

Screenshot showing regex test:

[image]

For Regex test see here: https://regex101.com/r/MMhn3i/1/